# nodejs and mongodb remote access through application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I have a web app setup using nodejs and mongodb and backbonejs.

When I run my app remotely and try to redirect to a different route through the uri, for example: http://www.myapp.com/route I get a net error.

In my route.js file I have the following:

```
  var mongodb = require('mongodb');
   var db = new mongodb.Db('dbname', new mongodb.Server('xx.xx.xxx.xxx', 27017, {}));
```

where xx.xx.xxx.xxx is my public ip.  However, when I change this to anything other than "localhost" and try to run node server.js in the root of my app I get the following error:

```
Listening on port 3000...

/var/www/html/pages/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:236
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1012:19)
```

I have already uncommented bindIp in my /etc/mongod.conf file as suggested in other posts.  I did this only to test and just to get it to work, but I plan to go back and play with the ip tables if I get this to work.

How can I access my app remotely?

Comment: This sounds like it could be a problem with your firewall settings. Have you configured your firewall to allow public connections on port 27017?

Comment: And do you get the same error when you try to connect through your LAN IP?

Comment: Thanks. That worked to get my server started. However, I still get the error on my browser.  In my chrome debugger tools window I get the following error: `GET http://localhost:3000/route/1?callback=jQuery191010623371391557157_1456063779865&_=1456063779866 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`  Even though in my view.js file where the button click event that does the routing is being handled I have called my web app router with the route I want to go to as follows: `myapp.router.navigate("route/1", true);`